# Solution to $u_{yyyy} = u_{xx}$ subject to a range of BCs - how to determine coefficients in general?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, orthogonality

I would like to solve the fourth order PDE

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial^{4}u}{\partial y^{4}} & =\dfrac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}\text{ in }{\Omega=\left\{ (x,y):x\in[0,1],y\in[0,\infty)\right\} }\\
\end{align*}

subject to

\begin{align*}
u & =-1\text{ on }y=0,\\
\dfrac{\partial^{3}u}{\partial y^{3}}-c\dfrac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} & =0\text{ on }y=0,\\
u & \sim0\text{ as }y\to\infty,\\
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} & =0\text{ on }x=0,\\
-\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+d\dfrac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}} & =0\text{ on }x=1,
\end{align*}
where $c,d$ are positive constants.

This looks like a problem that can be tackled using separation of variables. I have deduced a solution of the form

\begin{align*}
u(x,y)={\rm Re}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\cal P}_{n}{\rm e}^{-\left(\sqrt{R_{n}+\phi}+{\rm i}\sqrt{R_{n}-\phi}\right)y}\cosh\left(\phi+{\rm i}\left(n+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\pi\right)x\right)
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{P}_n\in\mathbb C$,

$$ \phi={\rm arctanh}(1/d)$$

and

$$ R_{n}=\sqrt{\phi^{2}+(n+\tfrac{1}{2})^{2}\pi^{2}}.$$

The problem now is that I cannot seem to figure out how to use the boundary conditions involving the second derivatives of $u$ to determine the coefficients $\mathcal{P}_n$. I am aware that in certain limiting cases (such as $\phi \to 0$) that it is possible to write the solution in terms of eigenfunctions and then use orthogonality, but how would I do it for this problem?

Is there an alternative way in which I could have written down the solution to make it more amenable to an alternative method? Is there anything to be gained by formulating an adjoint problem?

Comment: Your second boundary condition doesn't make sense. There is an obvious typo in the cubic exponent on the numerator but quadratic on the denominator, But it is unclear what the correct form should be. Also your solution defines $\phi$ in terms of $D_S$, but what is $D_S$? I see no other mention of it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have made those corrections.